# How to change the machine type of a Google Cloud SQL failover replica

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I recently changed the machine type for a Google Cloud SQL instance, but it did not automatically change the machine type for the failover replica. When I edit the replica, the button to change the machine type is greyed out. Does anyone know how I can change the machine type for the replica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment, it's not possible via the UI.

Until that's fixed, you can use gcloud to perform the change:

`cloud sql instances patch --project=my-project my-instance --tier new-tier`